# Query to check for commonality (Intersection) between each possible pair combination

Tags: mysql, sql, combinations, set-intersection

I wrote a program to generate tests composed of a combination of questions taken from a large pool of questions. There were a number of criteria for each test and the program saved them to database only if they satisfied these criteria.

My program was written to ensure as even a distribution of questions as possible, i.e., when generating combinations of questions, the algorithm prioritise questions from the pool that have been asked the least number of times in previous iterations.

I created one table, `test_questions` to essentially store the `test_id` for each test and another, `test_questions` to store `test_id`s and their corresponding `question_id`s using n rows per test (where n is the number of questions in each test).

Now that I have the tests stored in a database, I’d like to check that the overlap of questions between different pairs of test are within certain bounds and I thought I should be able to do this using SQL.

Using a self-join, I was able to use this query to select the questions common to Test 3 and Test 5:

```
-- Get the number of questions that are common to tests 3 and 5
SELECT count(tq1.question_id) AS Overlap
FROM test_questions AS tq1
JOIN test_questions AS tq2
ON tq1.question_id = tq2.question_id
WHERE tq1.test_id = 5
AND tq2.test_id = 3;
```

I was able to generate each possible combination of test pairs from the first n (5) tests:

```
-- Get all combinations of pairs of tests from 1 to 5
SELECT t1.test_id AS Test1, t2.test_id AS Test2
FROM tests AS t1
JOIN tests AS t2
ON t2.test_id > t1.test_id
WHERE t1.test_id <= 5
AND t2.test_id <= 5;
```

What I’d like to do but so far have failed to do is to combine the above two queries to show each possible pair combination of the first 5 tests – along with the number of questions that are common to both tests.

```
-- This doesn't work
SELECT t1.test_id AS Test1, t2.test_id AS Test2, count(tq1.question_id) AS Overlap
FROM tests AS t1
JOIN tests AS t2
ON t2.test_id > t1.test_id
JOIN test_questions AS tq1
ON t1.test_id = tq1.test_id
JOIN test_questions AS tq2
ON t2.test_id = tq2.test_id
WHERE t1.test_id <= 11
AND t2.test_id <= 11
GROUP BY t1.test_id, t2.test_id;
```

I’ve created a simplified version (with randomised data) of the two tables at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6f8e/5)

Note: I’m using MySQL as my DBMS but the SQL should be compatible with the ANSI standard.

**Edit:** The program I wrote to generate the tests actually generated more than the number of tests I needed and I only want to compare the first n tests. In the example, I added a `<= 5` WHERE condition to ignore the extra tests.

To clarify what I’m looking for as per Thorsten Kettner’s example data:

```
test 1: a, b and c
test 2: a, b and d
test 3: d, e and f
```

The results would be:

```
Test    Test    Overlap
Test1   Test2   2       (a and b in common)
Test1   Test3   0       (no questions in common)
Test2   Test3   1       (d is common to both)
```

Comment: In spite of your detailed explanation, I still don't understand. Sorry. You are not simply looking for tests that have more than x questions in common, right? So say there is test 1 with questions a, b, and c, test 2 with a, b and d, and test 3 with d, e and f. What would be the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a `group by` to your first query (basically).  I also added another condition, so the test ids are produced in order:

```
SELECT tq1.test_id as test_id1, tq2.test_id as test_id2, count(tq1.question_id) AS Overlap
FROM test_questions tq1 LEFT JOIN
     test_questions tq2
     ON tq1.question_id = tq2.question_id and
        tq1.test_id < tq2.test_id
GROUP BY tq1.test_id, tq2.test_id;
```

This is standard SQL.

If you want to get *all* pairs of tests, even those that have no questions in common, here is another approach:

```
SELECT t1.test_id as test_id1, t2.test_id as test_id2, count(tq2.question_id) AS Overlap
FROM tests t1 CROSS JOIN
     tests t2 LEFT JOIN
     test_questions tq1
     on t1.test_id = tq1.test_id LEFT JOIN
     test_questions tq2
     ON t2.test_id = tq2.test_id and tq1.question_id = tq2.question_id 
GROUP BY t1.test_id, t2.test_id;
```

This assumes that you have a table with one row per test.  If not, replace `tests` with `(select distinct test from test_questions)`.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.
Your answer doesn’t take into account the fact that the tables holds more than 5 tests (in the example data) but I was able to modify your answer to get the output I was looking for.
I’ll post the modified version as my own answer but I’ve accepted yours as the best provided so far.

Answer (score 2):

I modified Gordon's answer and this query provides a listing of test combinations along with their corresponding overlap (questions in common):

```
SELECT tq1.test_id as test_id1, tq2.test_id as test_id2, count(tq1.question_id) AS Overlap
FROM test_questions tq1
JOIN test_questions tq2
ON tq1.question_id = tq2.question_id
AND tq1.test_id < tq2.test_id 
WHERE tq1.test_id <= 5
AND tq2.test_id <= 5
GROUP BY tq1.test_id, tq2.test_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

- First step: Find all test combinations, for instance: 1-2, 1-3, 2-3
- Second step: Join all questions of the first test.
- Third step: Outer join the equal question of the second test if it exists.
- Last step: Count the equal questions found per test combination.

```
    select test_combinations.t1_test_id, test_combinations.t2_test_id, count(q2.question_id)
    from
    (
        select t1.test_id as t1_test_id, t2.test_id as t2_test_id
        from (select test_id from tests where test_id  t1.test_id
    ) test_combinations
    inner join test_questions q1 on q1.test_id = test_combinations.t1_test_id
    left join test_questions q2 on q2.test_id = test_combinations.t2_test_id and q2.question_id = q1.question_id
    group by test_combinations.t1_test_id, test_combinations.t2_test_id
    order by test_combinations.t1_test_id, test_combinations.t2_test_id;
```

I've added a test with no overlapping questions to your fiddle and removed the restriction to test_id <= 5, so you see pairs of tests with zero overlapping questions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e83aa/1

Comment: I like the way the results include the test pairs which have no questions in common.

However, the query is little too complex (subquery + 3 joins). I had been thinking of using a derived table subquery but figured there must be a more elegant method.

Anyhow, thanks for the response, Thorsten. It deserves an upvote but Gordon's answer was more useful to me.